# CSS adjusting table size

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code.

```
<html>
<body>
   <div style="max-width:1600px; min-width:900px;" >
     <table>
     </table>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question , when I have the screen resolution to 1024 * 768 then the table should fit the screen and when I increase the screen resolution to 1600 * 800 the table size should automatically increase its width. How do I do that ?

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: Some info about the contents of the table might help. If you've got data that is unwrappable (long character strings with no white space, etc.) it can cause your td to refuse to break lines.

Comment: yes my data does not have white space .Is there any way to make it 
to wrapped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to give width:100%; to the table inside the div, that should do the trick.

Comment: No not sure if you got my question. I have a table with 8 columns (I have not specified length for the <td> ). when the screen resolution is 1024*768 then the table should fit the screen,if it means some <td> should have multiple lines of data. 

But if I make the screen resolution at 1600 * 800 then those <td> which had multiple lines should try to accomodate more data. 
At present if i give width:100% I get a horizonta scrollbar in the 
1024*768 case (I want the <td> to display the data in mutltiple lines)

Comment: What you want is only accomplishable by using divs, not a table.

Answer (score 2):

`<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;">` should do the trick. The catch is, first row's cells widths will determine the corresponing columns' widths if you set. Otherwise it will be evenly distrbuted.

Answer (score 1):

In no case can you get a scrollbar... you must be having the td in a div something because of which a scrollbar is coming

try

width:100%;display:block;

or else paste the source of the table here... I will definitely help...

and there is not point Not declaring the td lengths... declare them equally...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
<body>
  <table style="width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
    ...
  </table>
</body>
```